# what would be the regex for 0 through 10 accepting decimals in .1 increments?

Tags: html, regex, zurb-foundation

I dont really know how to use javascript is the reason why Im using regex. I am using foundation's abide component. Does anyone know how I can validate 0 through 10 accepting decimals in .1 increments?

so 1.2

3.8 are accepted but

11

5.88 are not accepted

```
<div class="small-6 columns">

    <input type="number" class="small-3   small-offset-3 columns" required pattern="([0-9]|10)">
</div>
```

Comment: pattern is not clear though like what is 11 5.88 it is two numbers and it should check one by one right?
Where is your code which is not working?

Comment: I added my code, and those numbers a examples, I spaced them out to make it more clear

Comment: Do you mean the whole number is irrelevant but the decimal is required but can only be in the tenths place?

Comment: I mean that the user can put in either a whole number or whole number with a decimal however no more than up to the 10th place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern `^((?:[0-9]|10)(?:\.[0-9])?)$`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nO1cU7/1)

Per M42's correct comment (+1), use this modified pattern 
`^((?:[0-9](?:\.[0-9])?|10(?:\.0)?))$`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nO1cU7/2)

Comment: This matches `10.9` that is greater than `10`.

Comment: @M42 thanks, the other answer below does not match `10.0` btw.

Answer (score 1):

You may want following pattern for regexp

```
pattern="10|[0-9]|[0-9]\.[0-9]"
```

This pattern accept 10, 0 to 9 without decimal point and 0.1 to 9.9 (one digit & decimal point & one digit)

I'm not sure 1.10 is accepted or not, so this pattern is not considered

Comment: +1, for me it's the only valid answer here except that you have to put anchors or word boundaries.

Answer (score -1):

What you have to write is:

```
var myNumber = 10.5;

var Regx = /^[0-9]+\.[0-9](0)?$/; // edited two times to avoid integers
```

// or var Regx = /^(?!0)[0-9]+.0-9?$/; this one accepts zero-based values

```
Regx.test(myNumber);
```

Test for:

```
10.5 //true
10  // false
10.50 // true
```

Comment: This accepts invalid strings like `000.212.000.234`

Comment: well it is optional, it could be in the number 1.50 while this number can be written like 1.5